# Why does a Bootstrap 5 collapse not work in shiny::bootstrapPage?

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

Here is a working Bootstrap 5 page, made with a `div` and the BS5 dependencies via a CDN. Click on the button and some text appears. The example is directly from [Bootstrap 5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/)

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

# Does not work
#ui <- bootstrapPage(theme = bslib::theme_version(5),
  
# comment-from-here
ui <- tags$div(
  includeCSS(path ="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"),
  includeScript(path = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"),
# comment-to-here

  HTML('
  <p>
  </a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-bs-target
  </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
  </div>
    </div>')


)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the example, if you switch to `bootstrapPage` (and take away the includeScript, includeCSS), the example does not work.

This is standard Bootstrap functionality which I expected to work in shiny with theme version 5? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `shiny::bootstrapPage` uses Bootstrap 3, which doesn't have the same classes as Bootstrap 5, hence the missing functionality.

From `?shiny::bootstrapPage`:

> theme: One of the following:
>
> `NULL` (the default), which implies a "stock" build of Bootstrap 3
>
> ...

As you correctly observed, if you need functionality from Bootstrap 5 in `shiny::bootstrapPage` you need to load the required css & js. You can do this explicitly using `tags$styles` and `tags$script` or you can use the 'theme' argument of `shiny::bootstrapPage` as follows:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = 5),
  HTML('
  <p>
  </a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-bs-target
  </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
  </div>
    </div>')
)

server <- \(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can as well use `bslib::page(theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = 5), ...)` and you will get the functionality you're looking for:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- bslib::page(
  theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = 5),
  HTML('
  <p>
  </a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-bs-target
  </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
  </div>
    </div>')
)

server <- \(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you - so the `theme` argument I sent to `bootstrapPage` does not actually get the desired result. `bslib::page` is what I was looking for.